# Is it possible to get list of active users that have sessions in Keycloak?

Tags: session, single-sign-on, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I recently started using Keycloak and I can't find out how to get list of users (IDs or logins) that have sessions. Is it even possible?

I tried to call `GET /{realm}/clients/{id}/user-sessions` but that's not what I expected because there are duplicates of records (if the user has 3 sessions, then 3 records will be displayed and pagination doesn't work properly).

`GET /{realm}/users` doesn't have any parameters that I need too...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The `GET /{realm}/clients/{id}/user-sessions` correct API you looking for answer. It is accuracy to capture the multiple logged in by same user. You needs to filter out that users by filtering step after get API result.

Comment: @BenchVue thank you for your comment! This API is close to what I need but there's one problem... If I filter out users with multiple sessions then pagination seems to be broken. If I request 10 sessions and there will be users with several sessions, after filtering them out I will not have 10 user objects... I started to think that the only way resolve it is to get all the sessions then filter them out and paginate by myself... But performace is gonna be so slow

Comment: I don't understand why performance is slow. One API return a single JSON for all of session. Then filter out for getting user list. It is not a take time. Can you explain why it is slow? How many user do you have? and How many are usually logged on average?

Comment: There are like 500k online sessions average. Although, I'll try this because I don't need to make this API call often. Thank you!